# What is a good wiki with great spam protection that is easily hosted on Windows/IIS7?

Tags: windows, wiki

I am looking to host a wiki but want it to be very low maintenance. Spam protection will be key. Perhaps I can have a new account approval process and ban users who spam the system. I have looked occasionally over the last year and I have not not been happy with the available options.

I would prefer a .NET solution but I understand I may find a solution in PHP which will serve my needs. I would like to use SQL Server 2005 over MySQL so I not have to install and run MySQL on my server.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a really good wiki selection assistant and matrix of features at [WikiMatrix](http://www.wikimatrix.org/) - you can check that out for some of the technical options, although I don't know that it gets into spam prevention.